# How many infinite subsets does $\mathbb N$ have?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I attempted to write a derivation of the answer, but was told my mathematics was wrong; please correct me.

The cardinality of $\mathbb N$ is $\aleph_0$.
From this set, we can generate another infinite subset by excluding $1$ element.
There are $\aleph_0$ such possible subsets that can be generated like this.
We can generate an infinite subset by excluding $2$ elements from $\mathbb N$.
There are $\aleph_0 \choose 2$ possible subsets that can be generated like this.

In general, for any $i$ from $0$ to $\aleph_0$ we can generate $\aleph_0 \choose i$ such possible subsets by excluding $i$. To find the total number of possible subsets, we simply sum all the combinations.
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} {n \choose i} = 2^n$$

Based on the above:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{\aleph_0} {\aleph_0 \choose i} = 2^{\aleph_0}$$

$2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$
$\therefore$  the number of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is $\aleph_1$.

I realise that I excluded the number of infinite subsets who have infinite complements.

To account for this, merely combine any $k$ $i$ used in the selection above, and exclude all multiples of the products of $i_1*i_2*i_3*...*i_k$.
We have $\aleph_0$ such sets of $i$ with numbers increasing from $0$ to $\aleph_o$.

I didn't consider this when I first wrote it out, and only realised it after. I haven't yet updated my proof to include it. However, this wasn't the problem with my proof; I was told I did "bad mathematics".

Comment: They were right. I think it is possible (and also necessary, if you want to use it) to define binomial coefficients for infinite cardinals, and to prove a generalization of the binomial theorem for them. But it's hardly worth your time. The result follows immediately from the obvious observation that the set of _finite_ subsets is countable.

Comment: You **can't** suppose $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$.

Comment: Your explanation for infinite subsets that have infinite complements looks strange. Could you maybe explain why you think you can get all subsets this way? E.g. the set of all prime numbers, the set of all numbers with porperty P for any property (for which we know that there are infinitely many such numbers, even if we can't enumerate them),...?

Comment: I was going to count prime numbers and non prime numbers as two subsets, then work with that. But your argument for Property P (e.g the numbers in the Fibonacci sequence breaks my argument).

Comment: I was introduced to $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$  by a friend who gave me the definition $\aleph_{n+1} = 2^{\aleph_n}$. I'll ask a question showing the definition he gave me for it.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Why not?

Comment: @Dog_69, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Yes, I know. And you can accept it. I don't understand why you said he can't do it. Do you accept the Axiom of choice?

Comment: @Dog_69, AC is almost universally accepted. CH isn't.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Sure. But at the end of the day, both are statements independent of ZF. In fact, I think on time I read they was the first shown to be independent of ZF.

Comment: @Dog_69, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2622162/why-doesnt-the-independence-of-the-continuum-hypothesis-immediately-imply-that.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla To finish this interesting discussion, I only want to add that you are right. Many answers of the later question you have shown me say ''AC has applications in many areas while CH only on non-standard analys and it seems a good reason to avoid adding CH to ZFC'' (or semething like that). What I wanted to say before simply was the statement ''You cannot'' seems me ver strong, too much. In my opinion, you should recommend and explain him why he shouldn't suppose CH.

Answer (score 1):

> There are $\aleph_0 \choose 2$ possible subsets that can be generated like this.

No, the term $x\choose y$ is well defined only for finite numbers, not for cardinals. The number of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ without $n$ points is $\aleph_0$. Introducing a new symbol is not only not needed, but also misleading, since you've concluded incorrect things from that.

> Based on the above:
> $$\sum_{i = 0}^{\aleph_0} {\aleph_0 \choose i} = 2^{\aleph_0}$$

No, that is not correct. You've applied a formula that is valid for finite numbers only, not for arbitrary cardinals.

By my previous remark the number of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ without $n$ points is $\aleph_0$. And so the proper left side is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\aleph_0$, but

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \aleph_0=\aleph_0$$

which doesn't lead us to the correct answer. Because the collection of all complements of finite subsets is just not big enough, it doesn't cover all infinite subsets even closely.

> $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$

No, that is [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis). $2^{\aleph_0}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

> the number of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is $\aleph_1$.

Actually it is $2^{\aleph_0}$ by the previous remark. And your final result is only coincidentally correct.

One proper solution is as follows:

1. The number of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\aleph_0$.
2. The number of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$.
3. The number of all infinite subsets is $2^{\aleph_0}$, because that is the only solution to the equation $$\aleph_0+x=2^{\aleph_0}$$ by the fact that for infinite cardinals $\aleph_0\leq \kappa_1\leq \kappa_2$ we have $\kappa_1+\kappa_2=\kappa_2$.

> I was introduced to $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$ by a friend who gave me the definition $\aleph_{n+1}=2^{\aleph_n}$.

Not good. The proper definition of $\aleph_{n+1}$ is: the smallest cardinal greater than $\aleph_n$. Or in other words: [the successor cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_cardinal). Which is a valid definition at least under the Axiom of Choice. It is then the generalized continuum hypothesis that $\aleph_{n+1}=2^{\aleph_n}$, which is a statement independent of ZFC. And so we can work in a model where it does or does not hold. Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb N$ has $2^{\aleph_0}$ subsets. The number of subsets of size $n$ for any $n$ finite is countable. The union of a countable number of countable sets is countable, so $\Bbb N$ has a countable number of finite sets...

Answer (score 0):

Some of the math you did (plugging cardinalities into the combination function for instance) isn't valid. The function $(n,k)\mapsto {n\choose k}$ takes nonnegative integers as arguments; the expression ${\aleph_0 \choose n}$ is meaningless (if such a thing has been defined and is useful, it's probably the case that you haven't learned about it in your class).

Let $X$ be the set of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. To prove the claim, note that $\vert \mathscr{P}(\mathbb N)\vert =\mathfrak{c}$. Further, there are $\aleph_0$ finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ (since the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is a countable union of countable sets). Therefore,
$$\aleph_0+\vert X\vert = \mathfrak c$$
Since $\aleph_0+\alpha=\alpha$ for any infinite cardinal $\alpha$, we have $\vert X \vert = \mathfrak c$.

Comment: The number of finite subsets of $\mathbb R$ should be $\mathfrak{c}$ at least, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Hyperplane: Obviously yes, since already $|\{\{x\}~:~x\in \mathbb{R}\}|=\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: What does your fancy P mean?

Comment: It refers to the power set of a given set.